# Button Font Hover Color Defaulting to Site A Hover Color

Tags: css

I'm hoping someone can help. I've tried a number of fixes now and don't know what I'm doing wrong.

My site is Clintonholmes.com

The code I have for my "Want to know more?" Button on my home page is as follows.

```
.button1 {
    background-color: white;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button1 {
    background-color: white; 
    color: #663366; 
    border: 2px solid #663366;
}

.button1:hover {
    background-color: #663366;
    color: white;
    a.color: white;

}
```

For some reason, on hover, the font is grey instead of white. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!
Clinton

Comment: Because a stronger selector applies. To find it, set the `state` of your element to `hover` using your inspection tool of choice. If you don't have that option, you're using the wrong inspection tool. Chrome and Firefox have it. You will need to adjust your current selector to have a stronger specificity level than the one currently applying on the element (on hover state).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a CSS specificity issue. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

You can fix it any number of ways by using a selector with higher specificity. Here are a couple of ways.

Change `.button1:hover` to `body.gppro-custom a:hover`

Or you can change `color: white;` to `color: white!important;` in `.button1:hover`

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks Michael!

Comment: @Clinton np! :)